# Return filtered array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I though this was going to be straightforward. I have a dataset containing (foreach country) name, imfcode, lat,lon. I want to pass a code to a function that will filter the dataset returning the info that correspond to the code passed to it. So if I pass 512 I should get information relating to Afganistan. here my function, would someone mind telling me what I'm doing wring

```
function loadTrade(imfCode) {
  console.log ("Country code= ",imfCode)
  var sourceCountry=dataset.filter function(el){
    return el.imfcode===imfCode
  }
  console.log ("Source country= ",sourceCountry)
}
```

I keep getting an unexpected token and just can't see it. Many thanks

Comment: missing parenthesis `dataset.filter( ... )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the Parenthesis after `dataset.filter`

Change it to :

```
function loadTrade(imfCode) {
  console.log ("Country code= ",imfCode)
  var sourceCountry=dataset.filter(function(el){
    return el.imfcode===imfCode;
  });
  console.log ("Source country= ",sourceCountry);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, looking at this project too long. Fancy missing that. Thanks very much